# Unable to find function in FOR loop

Tags: r, plot, fft

My `version` output in RStudio,

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.4                         
year           2021                        
month          02                          
day            15                          
svn rev        80002                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
nickname       Lost Library Book
```

***My MRE:***

```
N = 32;
dx = 1.0;
m = 1;
for (i in 1:5) {
 a[i] = 0.5*(1+sin(2*pi*m*i*dx/N));
}
plot(a);
par(new=TRUE)
halfN = N/2;
delk = 2*pi/N;
dt = 0.5;

for (m in 1:80) {
  ahat = fft(a);
  for (i in 1:N) {
    if ((i-1) <= halfN) k <-
        (i-1)*delk
    if ((i-1) > halfN) k <-
        (i-1-N)*delk
    k2 = k*k;
    ahat[i] = ahat[i]/(1 + k2*dt); 
}
  a = fft(fft(a), inverse = TRUE)/length(a);
}
plot(a)
```

I get an empty output plot as follows:

[my_fft_plot_a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxPKl.png)

I am expecting to get the sinusoidal wave as initialized in the 1st for loop & `fft()` of the same to solve the diffusion equation.

Where am I going wrong with the code

Comment: Try `chat[i]`..

Comment: Yes, it works. I have made changes to my Q as necessary, now facing an issue in displaying the correct plot. Thank you

Comment: I was given a piece of advice that I can't expect to get at the indexes of objects I haven't created yet. But, I do not know how to apply it in this case. I think I am messing up with the initialization. Your valuable help is appreciated.

Comment: You haven't initialized your a variable, put a=vector("numeric",5) before the first loop.

Comment: @user2974951, It works now!. Will keep this in mind. Thank you